# Rigidbodies gaining speed when they shouldn't

Tags: physics

I'm trying to get the effect of a constant magnetic field on a charged particle. A really important aspect of this is that the magnetic field doesn't do any work on the particle, which in this case means that it doesn't make it any faster or slower, just changes its direction.

On paper, this works because the equation for magnetic force on a charged particle is q*VxB, or the cross-product of the velocity of the particle and the magnetic field times the charge of the particle, which makes the force always perpendicular to the velocity. The code I wrote for this is this:

`forces += charge * Vector3.Cross(rb.velocity, cons.constantMagneticField);`

If the particle is the only thing that exists, and it has some initial velocity, and the magnetic field is perpendicular to that velocity, then the particle should ideally move in a circle of constant radius, because the magnetic force will always be perpendicular to the velocity. With what I have now, my particle moves in a tightish spiral, gaining speed way faster than I'd expect it to, and at a rate that scales with the particle's velocity.

Is there a way to compensate for this? If not, is there a another way to get the behavior I want?

Comment: Keep in mind that a physics engine isn't evaluating your formulas continuously, like a differential equation. It's stepping them one discrete hop at a time. If you supply a force that's right for the moment at the very beginning of the frame, it will be wrong for how the particle's direction should have changed by the end of the frame. You'll need to integrate your changes over the frame duration to correct for this.

Comment: @DMGregory How would I go about that?